# What are the options for minors to invest in Europe?

Tags: investing, europe, eur-euro, minor, lithuania

I am teaching my daughter about finances, inflation, and investing.
We had opened her a minor account in Swedbank Lithuania.
During spring break she made several hundred Euros doing various chores and decided she wants to invest some of it.

I was looking into index funds in Europe but couldn't find anything for minors, apart from life insurance.
**What are the options for minors to invest in Europe** (Preferably passive index funds on sectors or regions)?

Comment: I think you should add a tag appropriate to which taxation jurisdiction you are in

Comment: @AakashM Hi AaakashM done.

Comment: How old is your daughter?

Answer (score 4):

**Your question**: What are the options for minors to invest in Europe?

**My assumptions**: You know how to invest as an adult.

**Answer**: What I have done with my eldest daughter is to set up a system where I let her invest her money (mostly from birthdays) in the shares/funds that I myself am invested in. I keep an electronic record on my computer in a spreadsheet (for easy calculation) and a written record in a notebook (for easy access for my daughter). Advantages of this method are that there are no (additional) transaction costs and my daughter can buy fractional shares of a stock.

Comment: I have a portfolio which has unlimited positions, I can even buy the same fund into separate positions. This way one could separate this more easily.

Answer (score 2):

My portfolio bank (ebase) offers specific portfolios for minors. These are then taxed in a special way, I am not sure whether they are on the parent's tax form or not. They do cost a little, so it might be better to have a shared portfolio like hkBst has suggested.